Youtube extension unable to scroll beyond a point
So I am building an YouTube extension ( similar to unhook) which hides some certain kind of videos, filtered by keyword. The problem that I am encountering is that only 3-4 videos are appearing on the screen after my extension filters the homepage out. I suspect that the extension is checking out the entire homepage and only returning the filtered ones, but isn't scrolling to go beyond the default scroll point ( YouTube has infinite videos on homepage, so it's impossible to get only 3-4 of them). What I want to know is how can we make the extension in such a way that we can scroll in such a  way that the extension starts to filter again and the videos keep on getting filtering and coming?
Initially I thought that the extension should be up and running directly for the entire home page, but it's not working that way, and only filtering the homepage up until a certain length.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
